# Datatable searching in specific range not working in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var table = $("#friendstable").DataTable({
    "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "columnDefs": [{ "orderable": false, "targets": -1 }],
            "ajax":{
              "url": $('#users-datatable').data('source')},

            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "columns": [
                {"data": "first_name"},
                {"data": "last_name"},
                {"data": "email"},
                {"data": "phone"},
                {"data": "age"},
                {"data": "twitter"}
            ],
            
                
  });

  

  
  $('#friendstable thead tr:eq(1) th').each(function() {
      $(this).html('<input type="text" style="width:100%;align=center;" class="form-control" />');
  });

  

    table.columns().every(function(index) {
      var that = this;

      $('#friendstable thead tr:eq(1) th:eq(' + index + ') input').on('keyup change', function() {
        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
          that
            .search(this.value)
            .draw();
        }
      });
      
    });
    $('#minimum-age, #maximum-age').keyup( function() {
      table.search().draw();
  } );  
   
});
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var min = parseInt( $('#minimum-age').val(), 10 );
        var max = parseInt( $('#maximum-age').val(), 10 );
        var age = parseFloat( data[5] ) || 0; 
 
        if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
             ( isNaN( min ) && age <= max ) ||
             ( min <= age   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
             ( min <= age   && age <= max ) )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);


</script>
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="label">Range</div>
    <div id="element1">
    <label for="age", id = "age1-label">From:</label>
    <input type="text" id="minimum-age" name="minimum-age"> 
  
  <label for="age2", id = "age2-label">To:</label>
  <input type="text" id="maximum-age" name="maximum-age">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Actually I have defined a jquery datatable and individual column searching on datatable but when I am applying range filter for age column the data is not getting filtered in that range. Can anyone suggest what wrong I'm doing in the code? Here above I have provided the Input range parameters for age and javascript code to display datatable individual column search and range search function.
thanks in advance

Comment: Your table is using `"serverSide": true` - so all sorting, filtering, and paging happens on the server. I don't think `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search` fires when using [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/index.html).

Comment: If you can help me with some rails article for range filter on server side with ajax call will be helpful.